# how to force putty to send LF (\n) on enter rather than CR (\r)?

Tags: serial-port, putty

I found that putty sends to my serial device \r when I hit enter. Is there a way how to make putty to send \n?

I found that it is possible to press CTRL+J to send \n - but I would like to press just enter.

Someone advised to set Terminal->"Implicit CR in every LF". But this does not work for me (I assume it is for what putty receives not send).

(I'm using putty release 0.66)

Comment: I think you want `Implicit LF in every CR` option.  I think you chose the wrong one?

Comment: like I said before and tested it again now: those parameters are for what putty receives... I did what you said and guess what? My program writes back to putty what it receives printf("cmd: 0x%02x\r\n",char); before I press enter I got "cmd: 0x0d"+new line. Now I'm getting "cmd: 0x0d"+two new lines... (extra new line putty transforms from \r I'm sending). But Like I said before I'm interested what putty sends, not what putty receives....

Comment: You will most likely need to use a different terminal program or write your own.  Where I work, we manufacture large machines that communicate via serial port and require CRLF, so I wrote my own terminal program to handle it all correctly.  You might check out [Hyper Terminal](http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal/).

Comment: I found this guy who forked putty to make it transmit CRLF on Enter: https://www.grzegorz.net/

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to find a way to make putty do this.

Using Tera Term however: you can configure to either use CR/LF/CR+LF on Enter (Tera Term: http://www.teraterm.org/) - which fulfils your requirement to transmit LF on Enter key press.

[image]